# I cannot play .wav file and a windows alert sound is played

Tags: python, winsound

```py
from gtts import gTTS
import winsound

Text = "Hello world"

Audio = gTTS(text=Text,lang="en",slow=False)
Audio.save("T.wav")

winsound.PlaySound("T.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

When the code is run there are no errors but a default windows alert sound is played instead of the test.wav file.

Comment: A quick look at the docs indicates that `gtts` only produces audio in MP3 format.  Saving the file with a '.wav' extension doesn't magically change the format.  And `winsound` only supports WAV.